# Do I need to clear my internal table before reusing it in a SELECT statement?

Tags: abap

When selecting data into an internal table using the `SELECT [...] INTO TABLE` syntax, do I need to ensure that I clear that table first?

Will the SELECT statement always clear the table for me, even if it fails?

Answer (score 6):

> Do I need to clear my internal table before a SELECT statement?

**No, you don't.** A `SELECT [...] INTO TABLE` statement **will always clear the target table**, regardless of whether the statement completed successfully or not.

As [the SAP Keyword Documentation states](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapinto_clause.htm):

> If `INTO` is used, the internal table is initialized. Previous rows remain intact if `APPENDING` is used.

So a `SELECT` with `INTO TABLE` will always clear the table while one with `APPENDING TABLE` will always preserve the original entries, regardless of whether the query succeeded or not.

---

And because I don't always trust documentation I ran a quick test myself:

```
DATA:
lt_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF but000.

SELECT *
UP TO 20 ROWS
FROM but000
INTO TABLE lt_table.

WRITE :/ |First SELECT. Table contains: { lines( lt_table ) } rows|.

SELECT *
UP TO 10 ROWS
FROM but000
INTO TABLE lt_table.

WRITE :/ |Second SELECT - { lines( lt_table ) } rows|.

SELECT *
UP TO 5 ROWS
FROM but000
APPENDING TABLE lt_table.

WRITE :/ |APPEND - { lines( lt_table ) } rows|.

SELECT *
UP TO 5 ROWS
FROM but000
APPENDING TABLE lt_table
WHERE partner = 0.

WRITE :/ |Failed APPEND - { lines( lt_table ) } rows|.

SELECT *
UP TO 5 ROWS
FROM but000
INTO TABLE lt_table
WHERE partner = 0.

WRITE :/ |Failed SELECT - { lines( lt_table ) } rows|.
```

This report will output:

```
First SELECT. Table contains: 20 rows
Second SELECT - 10 rows
APPEND - 15 rows
Failed APPEND - 15 rows
Failed SELECT - 0 rows
```

Comment: [Self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) since I swear I start doubting myself with this at least once a year and there aren't any good search hits. [Self-answering is explicitly encouraged on SO.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Expressing doubts about the accuracy of the documentation on the other hand might earn you a few (more) years in hell :-)